# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code

```
Date = site.xpath('my xpath').extract()[0]
            print "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD= "+Date
            DateString = Date.split()
            DayString = DateString[0]
            MonthString = DateString[1]
            Year = DateString[2]
            Day = getDayOfDate(DayString)
            Month = getMonthOfDate(MonthString)
            print "Type Year = "+type(Year)
            print "Month  = "+Month+"  Year = "+Year
```

I got this error

```
 exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

when I print the Year, I got `2014`
It seems that the `Month` is None

this is the exception

#### *********New Exception* *******

```
 exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: Which line? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: my problem is Year has no type

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Also, make sure you're returning something from `getMonthOfDate`.

Comment: @aIKid i just did the all exception, there is no need for month. pleae check the edited question

Comment: Thanks for that. One more question, what does `print Year, type(Year)` yields?

Comment: The title is silly. Of course you can concatenate two strings. The error message is clearly telling you that one of them isn't a string.

Comment: Can we see your full output for DateString after Date.split()

Comment: @aIKid it throws that exception in the question

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Not using `+`, but commas: `,`.

Comment: @Aidan it gives excpetion,

Comment: @aIKid it gives this `2014 <type 'unicode'>`

Comment: I guess that's what you want? So.. There is your answer!

Comment: @aIKid what? which answer do u mean?

Comment: The problem listed in the traceback is because you're using `+` instead of `,`. If you want the string, use `.format` or `str(type(..))`. 

However, the first error you give us isn't about this problem.. Why are you posting two different errors?

Comment: @aIKid the month is none, pleae check the functionn in the question

Comment: Why have you made your own custom date functions? These already exist in python date/time modules

Comment: @Aidan i didn't know about them. what are those please/

Comment: Guys, i have new exceptoin, please check the question again

Comment: Please see this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_date_time.htm , or this python reference http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back to the original answer:

`Month is None` because your function returns `None` because you don't spell `"August"` correctly. A better function would be:

```
def getMonthFromDate(s):
    months = ["January", "February", ...] # spell these correctly 
    for index, month in enumerate(months, 1):
        if month in s:
            return "{0:02d}".format(index)
    raise ValueError
```

---

Also still a problem:

```
type(Year)
```

will return a `type` object. You cannot add this to a string. That is exactly what the error message (which is not the one you gave) tells you. Try:

```
print "Type of Year: " + str(type(Year))
```

Or, as concatenating strings with `+` is unpythonic, something like:

```
print "Type of Year: {}".format(type(Year))
```

These also apply to error three, where you have an `int`.

---

You apparently didn't know Python does all of this already: read up on [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Well why didn't you say so? Please post the full traceback for the error

Comment: I have edited my answer. In future, if you could post the actual error message, that would be helpful

Comment: the month is none. pleae ckech the fuction in the question

Comment: You are ridiculous. How are we supposed to help if you can't even decide what the problem is?!

Comment: i solve the month problem. now i get this `Month  = 01  Year = 2014` so the month is not null and the year is not null.

Comment: but i still have the same exception.

Comment: Are you joking?! *The exception tells you exactly what the problem is.* You can't add strings and integers. Use `format`, as my answer suggests, or explicitly convert to `str`.

Comment: yes you help. just to be sure for another times. when i want to `+` str and int, i have to surrount the int with str(), right?

Comment: Better, just *never use `+` with strings*. Read up on [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

The exception basically says that one operand was a string—as you expected—but the other was `None`. So you tried doing `'Month = ' + None` or similar. So for whatever line this error appeared, the variable you are using there seems to be `None` instead of an actual string.

---

In your updated question, the error message is suddenly this:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects
```

So you are now trying to concat a `type` object to a string, which also implicitely doesn’t work. You will have to convert the value to a string first:

```
print "Type Year = " + str(type(Year))
```

An alternative way would be to use the functionality of the print statement that allows multiple arguments which are automatically converted to string and concat automatically:

```
print "Type Year =", type(Year)
```

Comment: yes month is none, pleae check the edit question, there is the function

Comment: The function returns `None` when neither of the months is inside the string. Also note that `"January "` has a trailing space, so if that’s missing, you’re not returning anything either.

Comment: the space was the wrong. i found that my self. now i have another problem, please check the question

Comment: The same thing applies over and over: You can’t concat strings with non-strings. You have to convert the non-strings first, or use the comma syntax for `print` as shown in my answer. Also, please do not keep changing your question for new problems.

Answer (score 1):

One of Month/Year seems to be None. From the code you gave it seems most likely to be Month

If you had used a format string (which is the preferred way) like this

```
print "Month  = {month}  Year = {year}".format(month=Month, year=Year)
```

It would not cause an exception, and be immediately clear which one is `None`

Answer (score 0):

It may well be that `Year` is fine, but `Month` or `Date` is not. Consider their values.